# Why gcc report error when I add Clobber list in inline asm?

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, volatile

I writing a C code to reproduce memory re-ordering, as following:

```c
asm volatile(                                     
    "xor %0, %0\n\t                 "
    "movl $1, %1\n\t                "
    "movl %2, %0\n\t                " 
    : "=b"(r1), "=m" (X)
    : "m"(Y)
    : "memory", "ebx");
```

I didn't quite understand why gcc complain :

> "error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints"

But if I removed "ebx" from the clobber list (keep "memory" only"), it would work.
What's kind of value should be put here in clobber list ?

Comment: You have specified `"b"` constraint so you are using EBX explicitly. GCC is complaining because it doesn't like explicit use of a register and a clobber for the same register. You have said that EBX is an output constraint so you've told the compiler it will be clobbered, thus no need to list it as a clobber I'm surprised it didn't complain about `"b"` not being marked for out (or input/output). It should be `"=b"`

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks, I get it, and just tried it. Exactly GCC complained because the register which used explicitly.
BTW, the missing '=' is my typo here, fixed it already.

Comment: not quite a duplicate of [How do I tell GCC asm that an input register is clobbered?](//stackoverflow.com/q/26942064) - this is an output clobber which is obviously redundant anyway.

Comment: This code requires an early clobber constraint modifier for both outputs as otherwise they may wrongly share a location with the output. For example: `"=&b"(r1), "=&m" (X)`